# mostrar 3 columnas dentro de un mat-table

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap

Estoy intentando mostrar 3 columnas (que son 3 iconos de boostrap) dentro de una columna (herramientas), a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación únicamente se muestra la primera la primera etiqueta , ¿cómo puedo modificar el código para que muestre las 3?

porción de html:

```
<table mat-table [datasource]="dataSource" matSort class="full-width-table">
<ng-container matColumnDef="herramientas"> 
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Herramientas </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></td>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></td>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></td>
</ng-container> 
</table>
```

Comment: Estás cerrando la etiquetas con </th> en los <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independientemente de que si estás cerrando bien o mal las etiquetas, creo que deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<table mat-table [datasource]="dataSource" matSort class="full-width-table">
<ng-container matColumnDef="herramientas"> 
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Herramientas </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
<i class="bi bi-trash">
</td>
</ng-container>
```

Todo dentro de un mismo mat-cell, es más creo que estos íconos serán botones para acciones así que sería bueno que los uses como mat-icons dentro de un botón, algo así:

```html
<table mat-table [datasource]="dataSource" matSort class="full-width-table">
<ng-container matColumnDef="herramientas"> 
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Herramientas </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<button mat-icon-button (click)="accion();">
<mat-icon>eye</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button (click)="accion();">
<mat-icon>plus-circle</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button (click)="accion();">
<mat-icon>trash</mat-icon>
</button>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: porfa vota positivamente la pregunta